# Limit of generalized principle of inclusion-exclusion

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

If we have the inclusion exclusion principle of the following generalized form,

$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \sum_{I\subset \{1,\ldots,n \} ; \|I\| = k } P(A_I)$$

and we take a limit of $n \to \infty$, does that approach $1$?

**Usecase:** We have a bug in a software which is extremely unlikely to occur -- but if it is going to be used in an extremely large userbase, it's likely that it *will* surface somewhere. I want to get a general probability about this occurrence.

Comment: I don't see why you would expect $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$ to be $1$ in general; what if $A_i=A_j$ for all $i,j$, and $P(A_i)<1$, so that for any $n$,
$$P(\textstyle\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)=P(A_1)<1\quad ?$$ Did you want to put some sort of conditions

Comment: Hnn, I see your point. So, in general, what does the probability approach?

Comment: Also, actually, in my case, $P(A_i) = P(A_j)$ for all $i, j$ does hold. So does $P(A_i) < 1$. Specifically, I have $P(A_i) = \frac{1}{c+1}$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Note Zev talks about the case $A_i=A_j$ for all $i,j$ and not just $P(A_i)=P(A_j)$. I don't think you'll find a general formula except what the original formula is.

Comment: Hnn, alright but then, given these two assumptions, is it possible to simplify the above rule a bit?

Comment: With regard to your Usecase, if you have a bug which will surface with probability $p$ on one execution of the program and you run the program $n$ times, the probability of at least one occurrence of the bug is $1-(1-p)^n$, assuming independence.  You don't need PIE for this.

Comment: @awkward Thanks for the simple expression. That should be much better to grasp. Can you please point me to some explanation of how I can arrive at this expression?